# Excel VBA code - How to clear values of a column of sheet 1 when two cells in sheet 2 are equal?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have  two sheets. `Sheet 1` contains all input. `Sheet 2` contains parameters. I want to delete certain cells of `Sheet 1` when cells of `Sheet 2` are equal.

Let's say, I am comparing cell D and E of `Sheet 2`. If `D3=E3`, then I want to delete corresponding cells for “pressure2” in `Sheet 1` (which is `B2:B3000`). If `D2=E2`, then I want to delete corresponding cells for “pressure” in `Sheet 1` (which is `A2:A3000`)

Does anyone have any idea how to do it by VBA macros?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a module an insert the code. The values of cells `D3` and `E3` of Sheet2 are compared; if they are equal and if they are not empty, then the range `A2:A3000` of Sheet1 is cleared of its values.

```
Sub ClearRange()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
 
    'Check if the cells have the same value and if they are not empty
    If (ws2.Range("D3").Value = ws2.Range("E3").Value) _
      And ws2.Range("D3").Value <> "" _
      And ws2.Range("E3").Value <> "" Then

        Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        'Clear the range
        ws1.Range("A2:A3000").Clear

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Comment: @nyeas001 You must ask a new question for that as what your are requesting is a requirement that was not on your original question.